# haystack elasticsearch connection refused

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

When I run `python manage.py rebuild_index` I get the following error:

> Failed to clear Elasticsearch index:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9200): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /haystack (Caused by : [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused)

My elasticsearch setting:

```
>  HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
>      'default': {
>          'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
>          'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
>          'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
>      },  }
```

It is worth to mention that I have indexed my data once before and all things went correct but I dont know why when  came back to project and restarted django project it went wrong!

Thanks in advence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you've forgotten to start ElasticSearch when you've returned to the project because the local connection is refused.

If you installed from the `.deb` file, then it should be wired into Ubuntu's `service` command so you can start it with

```
$ sudo service elasticsearch start
```

If you used the tarball, make sure you start it with something like:

```
$ bin/elasticsearch
```

More information in Installation docs http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation/

Comment: Hi Mahdi, what process did you use to install ElasticSearch and what platform are you on?

Comment: I used the .deb in Ubuntu!

Comment: Ahh - it should be wired into the SysV init scripts so you can start it with `service`. Updated my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was solved by just increasing the default timeout of 10s to 60s.

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
    'INDEX_NAME': 'index_name',
    'TIMEOUT' : 60 
},
```